# How do I make creation of my MySQL view respect the same character encoding as the database's default?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, view, default

I'm using MySQL 5.5.37.  The default encoding for my database is utf8 ...

```
mysql> SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA  WHERE schema_name = "my_db";
+----------------------------+
| default_character_set_name |
+----------------------------+
| utf8                       |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I create a view using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW report_toc_item AS
SELECT ti.*, pti.type_id PARENT_TYPE_ID
            FROM toc_item ti
            JOIN toc_item pti ON pti.id = ti.parent_id
            WHERE ti.type_id = 'sub_segment';
```

and then I show that view, the cndoing is showing as "latin1" instead of utf8 ...

```
mysql> show create view report_toc_item;
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| View               | Create View                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | character_set_client | collation_connection |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| report_toc_item | CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mytestuser`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `report_toc_item` AS select `ti`.`ID` AS `ID`,`ti`.`PARENT_ID` AS `PARENT_ID`,`ti`.`TOC_ID` AS `TOC_ID`,`ti`.`TITLE` AS `TITLE`,`ti`.`DESCRIPTION` AS `DESCRIPTION`,`ti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `TYPE_ID`,`ti`.`ORDER_NUM` AS `ORDER_NUM`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ID`,`ti`.`MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM` AS `MY_OBJECT_SEGMENT_ORDER_NUM`,`ti`.`ELEMENT_ID` AS `ELEMENT_ID`,`ti`.`UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID` AS `UNIT_TOC_ITEM_ID`,`ti`.`SHORT_NAME` AS `SHORT_NAME`,`ti`.`THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID` AS `THIRD_PARTY_PROMPT_ID`,`pti`.`TYPE_ID` AS `PARENT_TYPE_ID` from (`toc_item` `ti` join `toc_item` `pti` on((`pti`.`ID` = `ti`.`PARENT_ID`))) where ((`ti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'sub_segment') and ((`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'lesson') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'activity_practice') or (`pti`.`TYPE_ID` = 'unit_opener'))) | latin1               | latin1_swedish_ci    |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I make my view respect the default encoding of the database?  I would prefer not to hard-code the encoding into the creation of the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE mydb;  -- to see what the database's charset is
SHOW VIEW x;  -- to get the body
DROP VIEW x;
SET NAMES utf8mb4;   -- or whatever you got from the first step
CREATE VIEW ...   -- recreate the view.
```

Yeah, clumsy.

Comment: Is there any way to make the "SET NAMES utf8mb4;" part of the creation of the database as opposed to having to run it after the database is created?

Comment: Your Comment does not agree with your Question.  `CREATE DATABASE ... CHARACTER SET ...` applies to the _database_ creation.  `SET NAMES ... CREATE VIEW ...` applies to the _view_ creation.  I agree that that seems 'wrong'.